# jQuery on select trigger not working in ie

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I am using select dropdown to trigger different events by attaching unique classes to each select. For example :

```
<select name='topic' class='long box validate-select'>
   <option value="null">Questions?</option>
   <option value='First' class='select1'>Question 1</option>
   <option value='Second' class='select2'>Question 2</option>
</select>

<div id="faq1"> - </div>
<div id="faq2"> - </div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('option.select1').click(function(){
            $('#faq1').fadeIn('fast');
            return false;
        });
        $('.select2').click(function(){
            $j('#faq2').fadeIn('fast').siblings().hide();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works fine in Firefox.. but does nothing in IE (I checked 7 and 8).  Does anyone know how I should write this to make IE happy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wiring up the `.change()` to the select list instead.

```
$("select[name='topic']").change(function(){
   if($(this).val() === "First"){
     $('#faq1').fadeIn('fast');
   }
   if($(this).val() === "Second"){
     $j('#faq2').fadeIn('fast').siblings().hide();
   }
});
```

**[Example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/K9aHr/)**

Comment: Thats the ticket! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can rely on the `click` event working for an `option` element. Here's how I might do this:

```
<select id="myselect" name='topic' class='long box validate-select'>
  <option value="null">Questions?</option>
  <option value='First' class='select1'>Question 1</option>
  <option value='Second' class='select2'>Question 2</option>
</select>
<div id="faq1" class="faq">
  question one
</div>
<div id="faq2" class="faq">
  question two
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {

    $('.faq').hide();

    $('#myselect').change(function () {

      $('.faq').hide();
      switch ($('#myselect option:selected').val()) {
        case 'First':
          $('#faq1').fadeIn('fast');
          break;
        case 'Second':
          $('#faq2').fadeIn('fast');
          break;
      }

    });

  });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` fires on the dropdown element as a whole, not on individual items.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same answer in general as others but in addition if you are doing the same thing with all your dropdown options you can avoid the if or case statements by just changing the values in your dropdown.

An example is http://jsfiddle.net/UQKBQ/2/ . The second dropdown has a much simpler onchange function than the first.

Here the key line is:

```
$('#'+this.value).fadeIn('fast').siblings().hide();
```

This uses the value of the dropdown to construct the id of your div that you are showing. This technique isn't always possible so the switch one is good to know but in the case of a one to one mapping like this storing the element id in the value of the dropdown can make for a lot less typing (or copy and pasting).